# Is it possible to override an `.htaccess` directive after it has been set?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) `.htaccess`, which contains this section to protect hidden files and folders:

```
# Block access to all hidden files and directories with the exception of
# the visible content from within the `/.well-known/` hidden directory.
#
# These types of files usually contain user preferences or the preserved
# state of an utility, and can include rather private places like, for
# example, the `.git` or `.svn` directories.
#
# The `/.well-known/` directory represents the standard (RFC 5785) path
# prefix for "well-known locations" (e.g.: `/.well-known/manifest.json`,
# `/.well-known/keybase.txt`), and therefore, access to its visible
# content should not be blocked.
#
# https://www.mnot.net/blog/2010/04/07/well-known
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>
```

I want to add another folder to be excluded from this, but ideally, I'd like to avoid editing the code provided by HTML5 Boilerplate.

At the end of the `.htaccess`, how can I add a directive that negates the above conditions for a specific folder, such as `.example`?

Comment: You cannot negate what you have there - you will need to have another mod_rewrite directive in your .htaccess file that occurs before this one, that matches first.  Given you  can only have one .htaccess per folder, you are probably better off just using a custom one?

Comment: You can place `.htaccess` files in any subdirectory, that will be evaluated before `.htaccess` files in directories higher up in the hierarchy.

Comment: @wurtel ah, I think that's what I'm looking for, will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Since your root `.htaccess` file uses mod_rewrite to block access, you can simply create another `.htaccess` file in the folder you want to allow access (eg. `/.example/.htaccess`) and enable the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

By default, mod_rewrite directives are not inherited, so simply enabling the rewrite engine in the subdirectory overrides all the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file. The mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file are not even processed.